# How to implement getPrevious() method for double linked list?

Tags: java, list, linked-list

We were given the following code from the last assignment to use for singly linked list, but we're supposed to add in a `getPrevious()` and `setPrevious()` method. The following code works for the singly linked list as I completed the assignment and got 100%.

I searched online and read my book but couldn't find a solution.
For a singly linked list I would start from the head and iterate until the `getNext() == current` or something of the like. Obviously that beats the purpose of a doubly linked list, so any ideas?

```
public class Node
{
    private Object item;
    private Node next;

    public Node()
    {
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node(Object newItem)
    {
        this.item = newItem;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node(Object newItem, Node newNext)
    {
        this.item = newItem;
        this.next = newNext;
    }

    public Object getItem()
    {
        return this.item;
    }

    public void setItem(Object newItem)
    {
        this.item = newItem;
    }

    public Node getNext()
    {
        return this.next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node newNext)
    {
        this.next = newNext;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to to add an extra member similar to `next` that would point to the previous node in the list. Having done that, adding a getter and a setter would be trivial.

(You will, of course, need to change your implementation of the linked list to correctly populate this new member.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Can you explain how calling the getNext method continuously actually return the next item? 

I understand that it returns this.next, which is a Node. But how does returning the node move the current node forward? (I would assume it works in the same fashion for getPrevious?)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

So... where's the problem?

```
Node previous;

public Node getPrevious() {
  return previous;
}

public void setPrevious(Node node) {
  this.previous = node;
}
```

If you are to make the list a `doubly-linked-list` you have to implement the "other", opposite-direction link. You do it by adding nother field for each node. And you also have to update the field each time you modify the list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I was thinking of the exact same thing as the you code me.  But what I don't get is, how the links (both next and previous) are actually created. 

For example:
public Node getNext()
    {
        return this.next;
    }
Let's say we have a list created, how does calling this getNext method actually return the NEXT item? Is there some kind of hidden "counter" that increases each time we call getNext()?

In other words, how does returning this.next each time move the node "counter" forward? 

I think if I understood the getNext part the getPrevious will come easily. Thx!

Comment: These links are references to other nodes. When you insert/remove a node, you have to set its next/previous and its predecessor/successor next/previous references to that node.